# How much data can a bash variable hold?

Tags: bash

Let's say I want to parse the same log portion several times. I want to do data=$(grep "initial filter" file.log) and do the next filters on $data. Will $data grow until all memory is used up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems there are no limits except whatever is set by the OS:

```
$ yes=$(yes)

bash: xrealloc: cannot allocate 18446744071562067968 bytes (1617920 bytes allocated)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh , your method is wrong, use `mktemp` such as:

```
x="$(mktemp)"
grep mohsen /etc/passwd > $x


root@debian:/home/mohsen# echo $x
/tmp/tmp.yuMRWrJbRI
```

Then at end of your script you can delete your temp file.

At this method instead of variable, you use file.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with his method other than potential memory usage. Using this method you now have to worry about securing that file and then cleaning it up. And if `/tmp` is a tmpfs mount, and it often is, then it's going to use memory any way.